# Is there an alternative to ElementCollection/CollectionOfElements in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there an alternative to ElementCollection/CollectionOfElements in grails.

I need to create a mapping for a set of Components/Embeddable Objects.

For example A person has a set of addresses where Address is a embeddable object.

```
@Embeddable
class Address{
    ...
}

class Person{
    Set <Address> addresses
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is composition.

```
class Person {
    Address homeAddress
    Address workAddress
    static embedded = ['homeAddress', 'workAddress']
}
class Address {
    String number
    String code
}
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.2%20Composition%20in%20GORM

Comment: this does not handle the collection case